# Simple python list vs dictionary

Tags: python

So I am very new to python and I cant for the life of me figure out why these two statements evaluate differently,

> > > [3*x for x in range(1,11) if x > 5]

[18, 21, 24, 27, 30]

> > > {3*x for x in range(1,11) if x > 5}

set([24, 18, 27, 21, 30])

The top one makes perfect sense to me but why does the second print things in such a weird order? I know that hard brackets '[' are for lists and '{' for dictionaries.

Comment: In Python 2.7+, `{}` brackets can also be used to construct sets. The difference is that with dictionaries, you do `{key: value for key, value in whatever}`, while a set would just be `{someitem for some_item in whatever}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second one is not a dictionary but a set.  Both sets and dictionaries are *unordered*.  The elements are not stored or displayed with any particular meaningful order.

Comment: Sets and set comprehensions are described in the python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 0):

For dictionaries, you have to assig key, value pair, like {key:value}

So the answer for your question goes like below,

{3*x:3*x for x in range(1,11) if x > 5}

Output would be like below,

{18: 18, 21: 21, 24: 24, 27: 27, 30: 30}